# Help on removing the aliases from a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

my question is too easy (I guess), below is an example of trigger that I am trying to remove the aliases. I don't know what I am doing wrong I just can't get it right.

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE TRIGGER StartOfShift BEFORE INSERT ON shift
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(NEW.CashierCode NOT IN ( SELECT w.EmployeeID FROM WorksOn as w
JOIN shop AS s ON w.ShopID = s.ShopID
JOIN CashMachineCode AS c ON s.ShopID = c.ShopID
WHERE c.CashMachineCode = NEW.CashMachineCode ))
THEN SET NEW.CashierCode = NULL;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the aliases? It should be as simple as using the full table name everywhere you see an alias.

Comment: I guess I am gonna win the stupidest question badge on stackoverflow

Comment: Don't worry, I've seen *far* worse questions on SO.

Comment: I've given an answer, but maybe your efforts were failing due to the delimiter at the end of your trigger not matching the one set at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be what you are looking for:

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE TRIGGER StartOfShift BEFORE INSERT ON shift
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.CashierCode NOT IN ( 
        SELECT WorksOn.EmployeeID FROM WorksOn
            JOIN shop ON WorksOn.ShopID = shop.ShopID
            JOIN CashMachineCode ON shop.ShopID = CashMachineCode.ShopID
            WHERE CashMachineCode.CashMachineCode = NEW.CashMachineCode )
    ) THEN 
        SET NEW.CashierCode = NULL;
    END IF;
END@
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cez thank you for your answer. It works. Yes the delimiter was the error but why is that? The system, will let me accept your answer in 3 mins

Comment: @Sampas If you don't set a different delimiter for the trigger definition, MySQL doesn't know where the trigger ends, so it's expecting another `END` after your last (not properly delimited) `END`.

Comment: @cypher: Thanks, I was just about to say the same. @Sampas: I have added a line at the end to show the delimiter being reset to ; after the end of the trigger, which hopefully helps clarify things a little

Comment: I see. So `END@ DELIMITER ;` is the correct ending for this. Thanks again

Comment: @Sampas: "DELIMITER ;" at the end simply resets the delimiter. If it is omitted then future queries will expect @ to be used as the delimiter